# How do I cite multiple papers from a single book in the oxford humanities style?

Tags: citations

I am trying to cite multiple papers from each of several collections of papers, published as books (mostly as 'in memoriam' collections). They are not cited at the same point, in most cases. For instance, one of the collections has both a paper on building materials in medieval Syria, and one on the crossover of architectural styles in the Alhambara. I am wanting to cite these two papers in different portions of my paper. Do I cite each of the twelve papers from three books as entirely separate citations? Or is there some other thing I am supposed to do. It would be extremely confusing to cite the whole book and 12+ authors when I am only ever indicating a single paper and author at a time.